# How can we find the childnode element type in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a table cell and I would like to know if it has a text box inside or simply the span tag in it dynamically using javascrip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check whether there's an `<input>` *anywhere* inside an element, you could use `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
if (myTableCell.getElementsByTagName('input').length>=1) {
    ...do something with the input...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `tagName` attribute

```
function isInput(el){
  return /input/i.test(el.tagName);
}
```

or more generic:

```
function isElType(el,tagname){
   return RegExp(tagname,'i').test(el.tagName);
}
//usage
var isInput = isElType(myElement,'input');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something similar to this:

```
cell = document.getElementById('tableCell_ID');

spans = cell.getElementsByTagName( "span" );
```